# C++ read 2 lines in a while loop to a map?

Tags: c++, file, io

So i have a text file that's formatted with the key on one line and the value on the next line. I'm new to c++ and I'm having trouble finding a way to read the two lines into variables and assign them within a map.

So the text file im opening is formatted as so:

```
China
Asia
Canada
North America
Egypt
Africa
```

etc...

I'm trying to iterate through the lines with a while loop to assign China as the key and Asia as the value then to Canada and North America and so on. I have a bit of code written thats non functional right now since I don't know how to iterate the lines. Any advice is greatly appreciated especially since I know this might be a dumb question, I just can't find anything online that really answers this.

```cpp
CountryCatalogue::CountryCatalogue(std::string continentFileName, std::string countryFileName)
{
    std::ifstream continentFile(continentFileName);
    std::ifstream countryFile(countryFileName);
    std::string line;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> mymap;

    if (continentFile.is_open()) {
        while (std::getline(continentFile, line)) {
            mymap[line] = ??????
        }
        continentFile.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just call `std::getline` targeting the correct key in the map:

```
// rest of code omitted
while (std::getline(continentFile, line)) {
    std::getline(continentFile, mymap[line]);
}
```

This works because `mymap[line]` autovivifies the value with the default constructor and returns a reference to the new `string`, which can then be passed by reference into `getline`.

To handle the possibility of a key without a value, you may want to test both `getline`s, e.g.:

```
// rest of code omitted
while (std::getline(continentFile, line)) {
    if (!std::getline(continentFile, mymap[line])) {
        // Mismatch between keys and values, maybe emit warning
        mymap.erase(line); // Remove key which lacked value
        break; // Exhausted file
    }
}
```